# std::function<void()> accepting parameters

Tags: c++, winapi

I am studying this code and want to understand how it works. (Just wrote enough of the code for making my question.)

```
class AppWindow
{
    enum InitializeWebViewFlags
    {
        kDefaultOption = 0,
        kUseInstalledBrowser = 1 << 0,
    };
    void InitializeWebView(InitializeWebViewFlags webviewInitFlags);
    void RunAsync(std::function<void(void)> callback);
    ...
};

void AppWindow::RunAsync(std::function<void()> callback)
{
    auto* task = new std::function<void()>(callback);
    PostMessage(m_mainWindow, s_runAsyncWindowMessage, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(task), 0);
}

AppWindow::AppWindow()
{
    ...
    RunAsync([this] { InitializeWebView(kDefaultOption); });
}

...  /* msg handler */ 
case s_runAsyncWindowMessage:
{
    auto* task = reinterpret_cast<std::function<void()>*>(wParam);
    (*task)();
     delete task;
     return true;
}
```

Why / how is  the enum value is being passed to InitilizeWebView() ? Even if the std::function being declared just as std::function< void > , without parameters, it keeps and pass the parameter value? This happens just with one parameter? (Didn't try with more, but one parameter is being passed, I checked). Wouldn't the correct  declaration be    std::function< void(InitializeWebViewFlags)>     or  std::function< void(int)>  for this case, or it does not matter?

Comment: I believe your confusion comes down to understanding this line: `RunAsync([this] { InitializeWebView(kDefaultOption); });` - do you know what is happening here?

Comment: As I understand this is a way (lambda?) for passing a function call from the class to the class itself.   The function accepts a enum value, but is being placed on a std::function<void()>    I never used this std::function, but understand the idea.  What got me confused was that  the std:function isn't set to have parameters..   this could  be a function with 2 or more parameters, right? Just then would it need to be defined as std::function<void(int,int)>  for example?

Comment: Close, but what you're missing is that `[this] { InitializeWebView(kDefaultOption); }` is a _function_, but not a _function call_. It's an anonymous function (a.k.a lambda), that takes no arguments, and, when it is called using `()`, will execute `InitializeWebView(kDefaultOption);`. This lambda can be stored in (implicitly converted to) a `std::function<void()>` because it takes no arguments and returns nothing (i.e. `void`).

Answer (score 5):

It's being passed just like every other argument that gets passed in a function call, right here:

```
RunAsync([this] { InitializeWebView(kDefaultOption); });
```

This is a closure that calls `InitializeWebView()` with a parameter. There's absolutely nothing unusual about that.

But what's being passed to `RunAsync()` is a lambda that takes no arguments. Which is perfectly convertible to `std::function<void ()>`. This lambda happens to take no arguments, and returns a `void`, which makes it convertible to `std::function<void ()>`. And when it gets called, it calls `InitializeWebView()` with a parameter.

This is very similar (but not quiet logically equivalent to the lambda in the code, because of capturing `this) to:

```
void call_initialize()
{
    InitializeWebView(kDefaultOption);
}

// ....

    RunAsync(call_initialize);
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Minor correction: the example is similar but not logically equivalent to the lambda, because the lambda is capturing the `AppWindow* this` parameter.

Comment: This is true, tweaked the wording. You are free to make minor edits like that yourself, though.